# Didn't find class on DexPathList when trying to import library

Tags: android, gradle, libraries

I'm trying to import [this](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) library into my Android Studio 4.1.3 project.
However, I get this message whenever I try to run my project (which at the time, only has a call for this object in the MainActivity XML):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aquijanos.ruletatest/activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class PinView
...
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class PinView
```

These are my app gradle dependencies. I have done what the library asked me to do to import it.

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view-androidx:3.10.0'
```

}

What mistake am I making? because I don't know where to look for an answer anymore.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Individually including this library works for me. Can you please share your `MainActivity` layout where you have included this?

Comment: That library does not seem to contain anything named `PinView`. The project's sample app does, but that is not the library. Did you copy code from the sample app?

Comment: Nailed it. I assumed (wrongly) this view was in the library too, but it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it was giving me this error not because of some errors in the library, but because the View I was trying to import was not in it, but in the example project.

Thanks to everyone who helped me notice.